# How to shift bits in a color (hex value)

Tags: java, bit-shift

I have the following hex value store in a variable:

```
0x04a8f5
```

I want to convert the value to:

```
0xff04a8f5
```

How can I accomplish this?
I've tried to do this by the following operation:

```
int result = 0x04a8f5 >> 8;
```

Comment: The reason bit shifts don't work is because you don't need to shift any bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following example as a guideline.

```
val = 0x04a8f5; //Your value
val |= 0xFF000000; //OR 0xFF000000 with your value, and assign the new value to val
```

Note, this isn't bit shifting because if your original value is a 32 bit (or larger) integer, then there is already a higher order byte available that can store the `FF` value.  In other words, your original variable is actually `0x0004a8f5`. Using an `|=` assignment will OR `FF` with the byte that you are wanting to change.  No shifting necessary.

Also, shifting `0x0004a8f5` by 8 bits would result in `0x000004a8`.

Comment: oh shoot I didn't think of that. Good leaning experience.

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to prepend FF (1111 1111) to the front of your number, this isn't really a bit shift at all. You are just adding a constant to your color value.

As long as your color value is never going to take more than 6 hex digits to represent, you can just do:

`color |= 0xFF000000`